# Is it unconventional to define a subclass within it's parent class?

Tags: ruby

Is it conventional to define a subclass under it's parent class like below?

```
class Element

  class Div < Element

  end

  class Paragraph < Element

  end

end
```

Or is it more appropriate to make a module to contain the subclasses?

```
class Element

end

module Elements

  class Div < Element

  end

  class Paragraph < Element

  end

end
```

Or to create a "base" class in a module and define the subclasses within the same module?

```
module Element

  class Base

  end

  class Div < Base

  end

  class Paragraph < Base

  end

end
```

Or is it better to force a naming convention?

```
class Element

end

class DivElement < Element

end

class ParagraphElement < Element

end
```

It seems every library chooses a different namespacing/naming convention.

Which is the best to use?
What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The most conventional and best way to do this is with a module containing a base class and its subclasses. But let's go over everything.

There aren't many official sources on this; however, it is the style to use modules to contain libraries, code, and groups of classes.

## Subclasses in Superclass

**Pros**:

- Self-contained: The entire class system is contained under one name

**Cons:**

- Unnatural: Who would think to look inside a superclass for a subclass?

Having the subclasses in a superclass really depends on situation. However, any benefits of this method are also achieved by the module method. But in practice, this just isn't done. Classes are here to contain methods, instance variables, class methods, etc. But classes can be thought of as a last level of nesting -- you don't have a class in a class unless it's a very specific circumstance.

The one case where I can think of this making sense is a case where the only way subclasses are used is through the superclass, for example a `Formatter` class that has internal subclassses like `XML`, `PDF`, etc. Let's say that you only use these classes by doing things like `Formatter.new(:xml)`. But if we're doing this, the subclasses should be private and not accessible to the outside world anyway. And at that point, inheritance is a very C++y way and not Rubyish at all.

## Base class outside module, subclasses within

**Pros:**

- I can't think of any

**Cons:**

- Implies Non-conected: If Element is not in the same namespace as its children, what, beyond the name tells me that it's even related?

This method is very unnatural. It makes it look as if `Element` has nothing to do with it's children, or if looked at differently, that it's children are internal implementation details that aren't to be dealt with. Either way it looks like shabby, sloppy naming and bad code structure planning. If I were reading code using this, I'd have to look at the contents of the `Elements` module to see that `Element` was subclassed at all -- and this isn't the most natural thing to do.

## Class and subclasses in module (best solution)

**Pros:**

- Contained: The superclass and all the Element classes are contained in one namespace, allowing them to be easily imported, required, iterated, etc. Also assists metaprogramming.
- Includable: The classes can be easily `include`ed into any code.
- Clear: There is an obvious association between `Element` and the subclasses. They are obviously a bundle of functionality.

**Cons:**

- Encourages lazy naming: This does encourage you to name classes things like `Base` that are very ambiguous.

This is the best approach. It makes the classes a neat bundle, while still showing an obvious association and an obvious "Here, use my `Div` class" (as opposed to the subclasses-in-class strategy). Also, this is really helpful for metaprogramming, where having everything in a module is crucial to make things work. Finally, this works well with constructs like `autoload`, `require_relative`, `include`, etc. Those show that this is the way the language was designed to be used.

## Force a naming convention

**Pros:**

- Simple: No complexity here.
- Removes ambiguity: Removes ambiguity from short names like `Div` or `Para` by turning them into `DivElement` and `ParaElement`.

**Cons:**

- Archaic: Naming conventions to group classes or methods should only exist in languages that don't have a better way to do it, like C or Objective-C. C++ dropped it as soon as it got namespaces.
- No programatic grouping: These naming conventions, while clear to humans, make the class structure very cloudy to metaprograming code, and make it impossible for the program to deal with the classes as a group
- Pollutes global namespace: This creates many, many names in the global namespace, which is always a bad idea.

This is a *very*, **VERY** bad solution. It encorages writing sloppy, C-style code with little organization and little sense. These kinds of naming conventions should only be used in languages where there is no better solution, and Ruby has plenty of better solutions. Even defining all the classes in an array is better than a naming convention.

Note: However, if you really want to, you can define a naming convention on short names like `Div` or `Para` as long as you still keep them in a module, so that it's `Elements::DivElement`. However, this violates DRY, and I wouldn't suggest it.

## Conclusion

So, you really have two options. Just put everything in a module:

```
module Elements
  class Element; end
  class Div < Element; end
  #etc...
end
```

Or, put everything in a module with a naming convention:

```
module Elements
  class Element; end
  class DivElement < Element; end
  #etc...
end
```

I sugest the former for clarity, use of standard methods, and metaprogramming reasons.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem I have faced many times - you have some shared functionality and a few different implementation classes that use it - it's natural for the shared functionality and the namespace for the implementation classes to have the same name.

I have never had a problem defining a subclass under its parent class as in your first example - *except* for the fact that it has sometimes confused other developers on my team. So depending on who you are working with and what their preferences are I don't think there's any problem with this approach.

I would still prefer the second approach, with a different name for the namespace, if there was a name that made sense. If there isn't, I'd use the first approach.

I would avoid using names like `Base`, as in my opinion this sort of generic name encourages you to just throw any old stuff in there, whereas a name that describes what the class does will (hopefully) make you think each time you add a method if it really belongs there.

And I'm really not a fan of compound names as in your naming convention example, which I justify to myself with a sort of vague feeling that it's like database normalisation - each field (or class name) should contain only one piece of information.

Anyway, I hope this helps you. I can't really draw from any sources other than my own experience (it's for you to decide if you think that's 'credible'), as I do think there's no absolute answer to this question. It is in a large part subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Name space and inheritance are for different purposes. Use name space to encapsule a module within another. Use inheritance to define a module using the methods/variables/constants of another as a default.

It could happen in principle that you may want a module to both be within the name space of and inherit from the same single module, but that depends on your use case. Without discussing over a particular use case, it cannot be decided which way among the ones you presented is the best.